# Drop All Tables Except One in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have 100 tables in my database, I want to keep one only.

I tried something like below query:

```
DROP ALL TABLES EXCEPT my_table
```

But that doesn't seem to exist. any idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can build a DROP TABLE statement with multiple listed tables, and run the query using MySQL prepared statements -

```
SET @tables = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name) INTO @tables FROM information_schema.tables 
  WHERE table_schema = 'Database1' AND table_name <> 'my_table';

SET @tables = CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', @tables);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @tables;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Comment: Super piece of code - and combined with IN () you can keep multiple tables too

Comment: @Devart how to check for null for variable tables

Answer (score 4):

You can't drop multiple tables in MySQL.

The easiest in your case would be to export the table you want to keep (using a tool like `mysqldump`), then drop and recreate the database.

Comment: My table is so large i don't want to export it. It would be then easier to drop each table alone.

Comment: Then you should take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454328/is-there-a-mysql-command-to-implement-something-like-drop-tables-except-t1-b2

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why no one suggested to go to the **directory** :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Databases\MySQL\data\user_db\...
```

and **delete** them easily there? this is what I did and it seems working

Comment: It would work, if all the tables would be MyISAM tables.  If the database has InnoDB tables, then it wouldn't be that easy...

Answer (score 1):

If you have lots of tables, watch out for truncation by the GROUP_CONCAT function. It has a setting for maximum length of the returned string: group_concat_max_len

See: [GROUP_CONCAT reference manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

This answer guided me to the solution:
[MYSQL: How to define or get LONG string variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722623/mysql-how-to-define-or-get-long-string-variables/16725019#16725019)

Answer (score 0):

You can build all drop statements output them info file and use file after that

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'DROP TABLE ', table_name , ';' ) AS statement FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name not like 'table_to_keep' and table_schema like 'your_schema' into outfile 'path_to_file;
source path_to_file;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysqldump` , try it !

```
mysqldump -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD]--add-drop-table --no-data [DATABASE] |
grep ^DROP |
grep -v 'my_table' |
mysql -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] [DATABASE]
```