# Drop all tables with exceptions in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525512/drop-all-tables-command) question where it is presented a command to drop all tables from an sqlite database. Is it possible to add exceptions, i.e., drop all tables except table X Y and Z?

Thanks

**EDIT** I also saw that it is possible in [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251224/drop-all-tables-except-one-in-mysql). Is this script translatable to sqlite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PRAGMA writable_schema = 1;
DELETE FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name NOT IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z');
PRAGMA writable_schema = 0;
VACUUM;
```

Or, to get the DDL:

```
SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' || name || ';' FROM sqlite_master
    WHERE type = 'table' AND name NOT IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z');
```

Comment: If you have indexes on tables, this corrupts the whole database.

Comment: brilliant. Would you update your answer to include double quotes around tables as well? Query fails if table names contains numbers

Comment: SELECT 'DROP TABLE ''' || name || ''';' FROM sqlite_master
    WHERE type = 'table' AND name NOT IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z');